# using WCF in WPF and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, soa

I want to use `WCF` to expose my data layer.
I want to use this WCF in `WPF` project and Web application.
So i can call this service using `javascript or jquery`.
But one thing I could not understand that using WPF and wcf is not problem and is very flexible.
Means I am able to create `DataContracts` and `Service Contracts` and then later will decide on endpoints etc.
But so far my understanding is that to use using javascript I have to convert wcf into `wcf rest` services, by adding attributes to the Service Contracts.
Does not this breaks the whole principle of SOA using WCF, where I create WCF and using configuration will be able to use with any application silverlight, wpf, asp.net, php etc
and how I will be able to reuse my wcf data constarcts and service contracts code.

Thanks,
Daljit Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106). This toolset allows you to quickly and flexibly have both JSON and XML formatted access to your data layer using the REST protocol. The fact that you choose REST does not mean it is not SOA. And REST is supported very nicely also in WPF. REST just fixes your protocol to http.

For a discussion on REST versus SOAP, please read http://blog.tonysneed.com/2010/04/13/wcf-data-services-versus-wcf-soap-services/.